# Pandas: Create new column by filtering an existing column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column `gender` that contains males "E" and females “K”, I am trying to add two new columns that should include only the males and another for females. My code is as follow:

```
df=df.reindex(columns=["name","gender","year","month","count"])

df["M"]=df[(df.gender == "E")]
```

Comment: Try: `df['M'] = df.loc[df['gender'] == 'E', 'gender']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, using the `.loc` property will get you there.

This returns a boolean Series on the `gender` column and creates a new column matching the search criteria.

```
df['M'] = df.loc[df['gender'] == 'E', 'gender']
```